# formbuilder select value as object

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a form in which I have a multiple select field. Options for this select field are populated from received data e.g. *Tasks* objects.

```
[
{"id":7,"title":"Seven","project":1},
{"id":8,"title":"Eight","project":2},
{"id":9,"title":"Nine","project":2}
]
```

and my select field:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Select tasks</ion-label>
        <ion-select formControlName="tasks" multiple="true" (ionChange)="arrangeSelectedTasks()">
            <ion-option *ngFor="let task of tasks" value={{task}}>{{task.title}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

the function

```
arrangeSelectedTasks(){

    for(let task of this.addScenarioForm.value.tasks){
        this.selectedTasks.push(task)
    }

    console.log("selectedTasks: ", this.selectedTasks)
}
```

expects an array of task objects

Where `value={{task.id}}` passes `["7", "8"]` and `value={{task}}` `passes ["[object Object]", "[object Object]"]`

This results in my backend throwing BAD REQUEST error. I want to pass something like `[{..},{..}]` this from value.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use it **.map**

```
selectedTasks:any = [];

arrangeSelectedTasks(){
         this.addScenarioForm.value.tasks.map(task => {
           this.selectedTasks.push({task.id});
    });
        console.log("selectedTasks: ", this.selectedTasks)
    }
```

Comment: Replacing with this I still get with my console.log `["[object Object]", "[object Object]", "[object Object]"]`. Do I need to change `value={{task}} ` to anything different?

Comment: I did not get your comment, sorry

Comment: Do you mean `*ngFor="let task of tasks values"` ? It did not have any effect

Comment: As you see the first code snippet, those three objects are task objects, true it's not obvious from the snippet. Sorry for that!

Comment: didn't help sadly